# Execute actions on a html element added with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding an element to an html page using javascript when a button is clicked and making an onclick attribute on this button to alert something as a test to make it execute something but it is not alerting anything when this added button is clicked. Here is the codes.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<style>
  table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  th, td {
      padding: 5px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display:inline-flex;">
<input id="inptext" type="text" placeholder="Your name..."></input>
<input id="inpadress" style="margin-left: 10px;" id="inptext" type="text" placeholder="Your email..."></input>
<button  onclick="myFunction()"style="margin-left: 10px;" id="box">Add</button>
</div>
<br>
<div style="display: inline-flex">
<table id="tablename" style="width:80%; margin-top:15px;">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="buttons" style="float:right;width: 300px; margin-top:50px;">
</div>
</div>


<script>
var z = 1;
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("inptext").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("inpadress").value;
  document.getElementById("tablename").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tablename").innerHTML  + '<tr><td>' + x + '</td><td>' + y + '</td></tr>';
  document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML + '<button onclick="myFunctionedit()" style="margin-left:8px" class="edit" id="vda' + z + '">Edit</button><button onclick="window.alert("sometext");" style="margin-left:4px" class="deleteit" id="a' + z + '">Remove</button><button style="margin-left:8px" class="update" id="cvda' + z + '">Update</button></div><div id="zzza' + z + '" style="height:10px"></div>';
    document.getElementById('cvda'+z).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    z = z+1;
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the alert you are using double quotes:

> ```
> <button onclick="window.alert("sometext");" style="margin-left:4px" class="deleteit" id="a' + z + '">
> ```

Try changing it to single quotes:

```
<button onclick="window.alert(\'sometext\');" style="margin-left:4px" class="deleteit" id="a' + z + '">
```

Comment: Why did you put \  ?

Comment: Because you are generating the button dynamically, so the text is already inside another single quote. That way you need to escape it, so the browser doesn't consider it the end of the string.

Comment: The `\` is an escape character, so it treat's the following `'` as part of the string rather than the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="window.alert("sometext");" style="margin-left:4px" class="deleteit" id="a' + z + '">Remove</button>
```

makes for invalid html.

Try

```
<button onclick="window.alert(\'sometext\');" style="margin-left:4px" class="deleteit" id="a' + z + '">Remove</button>
```

On top of that, the `float: right;` in `#buttons` is making the buttons unclickable. You can either remove that `float` or give it a `z-index`.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L8ymqLwh/ (with `float: right;` removed)